# How do medals work in Battlefield 1?

Tags: battlefield-1

I've been playing Battlefield 1 since it's launch and have yet to win a single medal, or show progress towards any medal.

There are some medals which I should be showing progress on. For example the first checkbox for the "Order of the Iron Star" is "Get 20 kills as Assault". I've made over 200 kills as Assault and the box hasn't been checked.

Looking at the [official article on BF1 medals](https://www.battlefield.com/news/article/earning-medals-in-battlefield-1) it seems that:

> "There are always 5 Medals to choose from, and this quintet of
>   decorations is rotated on a weekly basis."

However I can't see anyway of seeing what 5 medals are available in the Battlefield 1 Companion. Without being able to see which medals are available this week I'm a bit stuck.

There might be in game options but since I tend to join my squad directly into battle from our PSN Party I can't remember seeing anything about active medals, or what I need to do to get them.

To clarify for Battlefield I've always used Battlelog/Companion to manage my loadout/ medals/ upgrades and the game itself for round after round with my online crew. I don't want to waste squad time trying to configure/ manage my soldier.

A Google search gave me lots of conflicting information/ opinions about how medals work.

So how do medals work in Battlefield 1?

Comment: I know you have to get the accolades in top-to-bottom fashion, but I agree, I'm going through "Legion of the Wolf" right now, and I feel as though I'm not getting my Squad Spots.

Answer (score 2):

You have to select the medal that you want to "track" before you start a round. Only then will your actions reflect in the medal.

For example, you have to select the medal and THEN get 20 kills as the assault class.

Comment: Also, it seems there's a bug in Operations where it doesn't update your progress on a medal between matches, but progress is still saved.  It seems like if you exit the program and go back in, it will update. It also seems to update while you are in a match - just not on the results or browser screens.  That will all probably be fixed next patch.

Comment: @ChaseC - how and where do I select a medal? My gameplay goes Deploy > Battle > Scoreboard - rinse & repeat.

Comment: While a map is loading, press OPTIONS on the controller, you'll open a menu that allows you to change which medal you are tracking.

Comment: @ChaseC - another question. If you don't select a medal to track but you still tick off the checklist of one of the five active medals are you automatically awarded that medal? Or are only tracked medals awarded?

Comment: @BaronGrivet you can't get any award if you are not tracking a medal. You are awarded a medal only after finishing all checklists. Only tracked medals would be awarded.

Answer (score 2):

Medals are working a bit different in BF1 than in previous games. You can only earn up to 5 medals a week now and you have to select which one you want to track. Medals have different stages and they have to be completed in order.

If found this guide pretty useful. It has a complete list of all medals as well:
http://www.battleblog.net/single-post/2016/11/22/battlefield1-medals-list-guide